# Koopmann von Neumann (KvN) Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, wavefunction, hilbert-space

I was just wondering does anyone have any informative sources apart from the obvious wikipedia articles regarding [Koopmann von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics) (KvN) theory? Or if its possible could someone explain the basic premise? 
I just cannot find anything on the web at all!

Comment: Thank you all very much, I have chose the answer which will help me most, since it starts pretty much exactly where I'm familiar with: the Liouville equation. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See for example [Topics in Koopman-von Neumann Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301172) by D. Mauro. This should be one of the most extensive overviews of KvN Theory, it also contains some examples of applying this theory to some well known problems such as Aharonov-Bohm Effect.

Answer (score 0):

Koopman’s foundational paper is freely available on pubmed (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1076052/) and is an excellent resource by itself. Beyond that, the usual approach to teaching KvN is through analogy with the modern forulation quantum mechanics in complex separable Hilbert space, i.e the *state space* (see, for example, http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Hilbert-Spaces.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice and introductory presentation on the [first book](http://books.google.it/books/about/I_Functional_Analysis.html?id=rpFTTjxOYpsC&redir_esc=y) of Reed and Simon, Section VII.4, and a detailed bibliography at the end of the section.